# Adding alphabets to a Java HashSet

Tags: java, char, set, hashset

I want to add all lowercase alphabets to a Java HashSet. For this I use the following code snippet:

```
for(char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++)  
    set.add(c);
```

Is there a better way to do this, like one in which I don't have to iterate over all the alphabets?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want a set with all lower case characters from all alphabets? When you add all accented versions from latin, greek, and cyrillic alphabets it's going to be a very messy set...

Comment: @Shmosel Feel free to post an answer.  My Java 8 is extremely weak, because we only use Java 7 here :-(

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 using `IntStream`, I think you should be able to get all lowercase `Character` values like this:

```
Set<Character> set = IntStream.rangeClosed(Character.MIN_VALUE, Character.MAX_VALUE)
        .filter(Character::isLowerCase)
        .mapToObj(i -> Character.valueOf((char) i))
        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

This `Set<Character>` contains 1,402 `Character` objects.

If you don't want to box the `char` values as `Character` objects, and don't mind using a third-party library, you can do the following with [Eclipse Collections](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/):

```
CharSet charSet = IntInterval.zeroTo(Character.MAX_VALUE)
    .asLazy()
    .select(Character::isLowerCase)
    .collectChar(i -> (char) i)
    .toSet();
```

This `CharSet` contains 1,402 `char` values.

If you don't want ALL lowercase letters, then just change your range to the ones you are looking for.  For example:

```
CharSet charSet = IntInterval.fromTo('a', 'z')
        .asLazy()
        .collectChar(i -> (char) i)
        .toSet();
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections

Comment: is that a public field literally called `mutable`?